# Naming thread of CompletableFuture

Tags: java, multithreading

Is it possible to set a name format of thread created by CompletableFuture? To achive something like below on Debugger:

```
Thread[pool-1-my-named-thread-1]
```

Comment: `Thread.currentThread().setName("....")` can set name of current thread. But you should instead use `ThreadFactory` to automatically name your threads, eg via https://guava.dev/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ThreadFactoryBuilder.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  You can [pass a custom Executor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#runAsync%28java.lang.Runnable,java.util.concurrent.Executor%29) which names the threads it creates:

```
AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

ForkJoinPool.ForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory factory = pool -> {
    ForkJoinWorkerThread thread =
        ForkJoinPool.defaultForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory.newThread(pool);

    thread.setName("user6778654-" + counter.incrementAndGet());

    return thread;
};

CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(task,
    new ForkJoinPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(),
        factory, null, false));

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [`ThreadFactory`](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ThreadFactoryBuilder.html) to create named threads or an ExecutorService which vends out named threads.

Also by default `CompletableFuture` uses the ForkJoinPool, so you need to also [pass your custom executor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#runAsync%28java.lang.Runnable,java.util.concurrent.Executor%29).

```
ExecutorService customExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10,new ThreadFactoryBuilder()
                .setNameFormat("your-name-of-choice-%d")
                .setThreadFactory(Executors.defaultThreadFactory())
                .build());
CompletableFuture.runAsync(()->System.out.println("Example Runnable"),customExecutor);
```